# Access nautilus settings in Gnome Fallback/Flashback

Tags: nautilus, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

I'm running Xenial, and file/folder settings are only accessible via the unity toolbar.

However, I run gnome panel and so I can't access these preferences. Is there a way I can either get my menu attached to the window again, and not the unity toolbar, or trigger the file/folder preferences via command line?

I know I can run gsettings commands, or use dconf, but I want to be able to see the file/folder settings dialog.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of how your nautilus looks right now?

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to Bionic (18.04)? It works there. :) Don' remember details, but I think this is bug in ubuntu patches for nautilus.

Comment: That's a good enough answer for me. I'll upgrade to the next LTS release as long as I never have to switch to Unity.